# Module must be set

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I try to use the new [Dagger Android injection thing](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) that works so far.

Now I want to extend it to my needs.

In my [`MainActivityModule`](https://github.com/the4thfloor/ArchitectureComponentsDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/the4thfloor/acd/ui/main/MainActivityModule.kt) I added a [`TestModule`](https://github.com/the4thfloor/ArchitectureComponentsDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/the4thfloor/acd/di/TestModule.kt):

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(TestModule::class))
    internal abstract fun contributeMainActivityInjector(): MainActivity
}
```

The `TestModule` is really simple:

```
@Module
internal abstract class TestModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideTest(): String {
        return "foo bar"
    }
}
```

But I get this error: `TestModule must be set`

I looked into the generated source code but can't find a hint what I have to do. I searched for this at Google too but found only simple examples :-(

What have I forgotten? You can find the complete app at [GitHub](https://github.com/the4thfloor/ArchitectureComponentsDemo).

**Edit**

As Jeff Bowman sayed the `provideTest()` needs to be static. When I create a Java class like this:

```
@Module
public class TestModule {

    @Provides
    static String provide() {
        return "foo bar";
    }
}
```

it works.

So the final question: How to make this in Kotlin? This doesn't work:

```
@Module
internal abstract class TestModule {

    companion object {

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        internal fun provideTest(): String {
            return "foo bar"
        }
    }
}
```

So I need another way to create a static method.

Comment: In Java, you would expect the `@Provides` method to be static, which means nothing uses a `TestModule` instance. However, [Kotlin doesn't support static methods as such](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#companion-objects). I'm not familiar enough with Kotlin to supply a true answer, but it seems Dagger requires an instance because `provideTest` is non-static, and doesn't believe it can instantiate TestModule through a public argumentless constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yeh I found a solution :-)

The Kotlin way to get a `static` method is to put the method in a `companion object` but now Dagger throws an error that the `@Provides` can only be used in a `@Module`. To fix this I annotated the `companion object` too

```
@Module
internal abstract class TestModule {

    @Module
    companion object {

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        internal fun provideTest(): String {
            return "foo bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, that's a bit cleaner in case you need to mock / replace dependencies in tests, would be to avoid making the class abstract, and keep the provides not static, like this:

```
@Module
internal class TestModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideTest(): String {
        return "foo bar"
    }

}
```